# How to change datetime_index in Rodeo Python dataframe to datetime?

Tags: python, dataframe, date-range, rodeo

in Rodeo I created a dataframe with column 'Date' as a range of Date by inputing:

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range('2017-01-01',periods=100,freq='D'),
    'Value': np.random.normal(10,5,size=100).tolist()
})
```

However, when I click on the dataframe, it shows

Date
1483228800000
1483315200000
1483401600000
1483488000000
...

in the 'Date' column. Yet, the datetime format works properly when I try:

```
>>> temp_df.Date.head()
0   2017-01-01
1   2017-01-02
2   2017-01-03
3   2017-01-04
4   2017-01-05
```

May I know what am I missing in my code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I believe it is a numerical representation of dates and format is still fine.

Comment: Is there any way that I can change it to datetime format so that I can read my dataframe for data analysis more easily?

Comment: I am not aware of the Rodeo and it is internal representation of the dates. You can still perform your analysis without any troubles. you can still try to convert the type of the column to datetime using pd.to_datetime if it helps. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Just so you know, Rodeo's developer (yhat) was bought out and Rodeo is no longer supported/maintained.

Comment: pd.to_datetime doesn't work. It still shows index in dataframe.

Comment: This is sad. Is there any IDE similar to Rodeo that is easy to pick up? I am switching from R to Python so I am looking for some IDE similar to RStudio environment.